# I'm having trouble with templates

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

I'm having trouble figuring out how some websites templates are designed. Specifically speaking, the gradient parts. Look at this site as an example:

[Gradient example site](http://forums.lotro.com/)

If you right click on any of the gradients on this website and view that element's background you will notice that the background is in a gradient grayscale. But when the page is loaded it shows a blue gradient. Why doesn't the background show in a blue gradient just like the page shows? (I think I sound like a noob for asking, but I must know.)

Comment: Those gradients are just images, if you really want to use css-gradient you can check out: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: If you check closely you will see that a blue color background is added `background-color: #002B6B;
border-color: #00419C;`

Comment: @janith: If they add the background color through style how do they keep it from being one solid color?

Comment: You have the solid background color, and on top of it you have the transparent png. Together they give the gradient.

Answer (score 2):

It uses 2 layers.

1. the main wrapper with it's colored background.
2. inner wrapper with an 50% alpha channel image with gray gradient.

[See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/IorgaMihai/r4Unz/2/)

Answer (score -1):

It probably has an alpha channel set and a coloured background.

Tip: use a tool like Firebug (https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/) to figure stuff like this out (that's how I did it ;-)).